# Is there a miniture atmospheric water vapor condenser?

Tags: building-design, compressed-air, water-resources

I am looking to add a condenser for a plant preserving container. The plants need water and I was wondering if I can have a passive method to condense atmospheric moisture to water. My container is small and I would like the condenser to be as small as 30 cm$^3$ (but I can be flexible). Is there a current passive miniature air well (condenser)?

My container design can be changed to fit the condenser (so it is irrelevant). Therefore I would like to find a passive condenser that is small enough but enough to water a plant continuously.

(note: I am not asking for a product, I am asking for a mechanism or a technology or a method)

Comment: Seeking product or vendor recommendations will get your question closed so I suggest that you [edit] to fix that. Why can you not seal the container to make a closed recycling environment?

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: I am asking for a technology or a method. I am asking if it is possible to design by myself.